# Pickable matplotlib plot in tkk frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I would like to have a GUI where one part of the interface contains a plot and the rest of the window some tools to work around the plot.

I would like to use mpl_connect to connect the matplotlib canvas with the tkk frame so that I can choose points in the plot to work with.

This was my try, which cowardly refuses to do what I think it should do:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

class Frame_examples_program():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("Amazing GUI 5000")
        self.create_widgets()


    def create_widgets(self):
        self.window['padx'] = 10
        self.window['pady'] = 10

        # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
        # Frame
        frame1 = ttk.Frame(self.window, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S, padx=0, pady=0)

        frame2 = ttk.Frame(self.window, relief=tk.RIDGE)
        frame2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S, padx=0, pady=0)        
        self.PlotFrame(frame1, frame2)


    class PlotFrame():
        # The plot
        def __init__(self, parent1, parent2):
            self.parent1 = parent1
            self.parent2 = parent2
            canvas = self.plot()
            self.plot_toolbar(canvas)

        def plot(self):
            # the actual plot
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            plt.imshow(np.ones((100,100)),picker=True)
            canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self.parent1)
            canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onclick)
            return(canvas)

        def plot_toolbar(self, canvas):
            # the tool bar to the plot
            toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self.parent2)
            toolbar.update()
            canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=1)
            canvas.draw()

        def onclick(self, event):
            # the devilish thing that does nothing!
            print('WOHOOOO')




# Create the entire GUI program
program = Frame_examples_program()

# Start the GUI event loop
program.window.mainloop()
```

As you'll see when you run this, the matplotlib toolbar nicely works, but I just can't call the onclick event! Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `PlotFrame` instance that is created via `self.PlotFrame(frame1, frame2)` is not stored anywhere and hence garbage collected. At the point where you expect the callback to happen this instance does not exist in memory anymore.

Solution: Make sure to keep a reference to the `PlotFrame` at all time, e.g.

```
self.myplot = self.PlotFrame(frame1, frame2)
```

Note that this is a more or less general rule: You would almost never instantiate a class without storing it anywhere. In case you do and don't run into trouble, that would mostly be sign that the class is not needed at all.